# Class execution order of TestNG tests

Tags: selenium, testng

I have read many of the articles out here on this topic and have yet to find the one that resolves my issue.

Goal:

1. Get test classes defined in testng.xml file to execute in order
   listed in the file.
2. Have all methods defined within each class fire in order listed
   (this works)
3. Only have a single browser window open at any given time (NO
   Parallel execution)

Each test class has an init method that initializes the browser, so I understand why I am getting n number of browser windows open right off the bat, one for each test class.

**What I'd like to happen is...**

Kick off Test Class A
Run all methods in Test Class A
Clsoe the browser via @AfterTest method in Test Class A
Move on to Test Class B
...

I am hoping there is some way that I can get TestNG to do this.  Also, I am kicking off the tests from maven command line using 'mvn test -Dbrowser=chrome' with the surefire plugin that calls on my defined TestNG.xml file.

**Current TestNG.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="com.infdig.qa.Listeners" />
        <listener class-name="com.infdig.qa.resources.ExtentReporterNG" />
    </listeners>
    <test name="Regression"  >
        <classes>
            <class name="com.infdig.qa.BasicSiteNavigationTests">
                <methods>
                    <include name="openedToDashboard" />
                    <include name="navigateToActiveReleasePreset" />
                    <include name="navigateToReleasePresets" />
                    <include name="navigateToComponentSelections" />
                    <include name="navigateToOrderSlices" />
                    <include name="navigateToAbout" />
                </methods>
            </class>
            <class name="com.infdig.qa.AboutPageTests">
                <methods>
                    <include name="validateAboutPageDescriptionText" />
                    <include name="validateAboutPageLegalText" />
                    <include name="validateAboutPageHelpText" />
                    <include name="validateHelpLinkToInfinityPortal" />
                </methods>
            </class>
            <class name="com.infdig.qa.ReleasePresetTests">
                <methods>
                    <include name="deleteAllExistingPresets" />
                    <include name="createInitialPresets" />
                    <include name="changeActivePreset" />
                    <include name="addNewReleasePreset" />
                    <include name="deletePreset" />
                    <include name="addMultiplePresets" />
                    <include name="searchForPresetByName" />
                    <include name="deleteMultiplePresetsAtOnce" />
                    <include name="validateHelpTextIsAccurate" />
                </methods>
            </class>
            <class name="com.infdig.qa.OrderSliceTests">
                <methods>
                    <include name="deleteAllSlices" />
                    <include name="createNewOrderSlice" />
                    <include name="editExistingOrderSlice" />
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your TestNG xml runner file doesn't have an important parameters

- preserve-order="true", to run by order. [Here](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/preserve-order-in-testng) you can find more
  details.

I think you're mixing up the AfterTest method and AfterClass method, after test method will close your browser once, **WHY?**
Because in the xml file you have 1 test tag only , AfterTest method is running accordingly to test tags. As you wrote I understand that you wanna run test methods of class A then of class B, to do that you must put each class tag inside test tag which means you have 4 class tags so that you need 4 test tags.

**OR**

You can keep the xml like above but you have to change AfterTest method to AfterClass.

Here are the annotations differences:

- @AfterTest: The annotated method will  be run after all the test
  methods belonging to the classes inside the  tag have run.
- @AfterClass: The annotated method will be run after all the test  methods in the current class have been run.
- @AfterMethod: The    annotated method will be run after each test
  method.

Comment: Excellent!  That gave me the result I was after.  Thank you!